# redshift interleaved_skew high causing slow query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

i have a query (insert) which is taking around 15 minutes and should only be taking a few minutes at most. when checking the skew levels it showed columns around the 2 mark so i decided to run a `vacuum reindex *tablename*`

the skew levels are still high after the reindex. Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you think that the slow speed is related to the skew? How many rows are you inserting per INSERT statement? Is it hundreds/thousands, or one-at-a-time?

Comment: I can't say for sure, since I don't know your data, but this can be caused by having too many rows with the same values in your sort key columns.

Comment: about 65000 rows for the INSERT statement. the skew reason because i have the same database on a different environment with normal skew levels. The databases structure is the same , data stored on them is different.

Comment: @MaxGanzII i have a column which has the exact same value throughtout the table. it isnt distkey and sortkey is 2. am fairly sure now it is this column causing the slowness because when i remove from WHERE clause the query finishes in seconds. how to fix this?

Comment: Interleaved sorting has some complexity to it and it has to be understood to be used correctly.  I can't explain interleaved sorting to you in a SO post; there's too much which need to be explained even to be begin explaining about interleaved sorting itself.  All I can say to you is the direct answer to your question, which is that this cannot be fixed, as it is an inherent property of interleaved sorting.  Given your system as a whole, quite possibly there would be other changes you could make to work aorund it, but to know what they would be, you need to understand interleaved sorting.

Comment: can you remove an interleaved sort key from a column with alter table....?